# iOS StreamingKit 'seek' command causes audio stream to report incorrect progress values

Tags: ios, audio, streaming

We are using StreamingKit (https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit) to play from a list of streaming m4a audio sources that the user can move back and forth between freely.

We remember the position in each stream, and we perform a seek when the item begins playing (in the delegate method didStartPlayingQueueItemId), to return to a remembered spot in the audio for that item.

Immediately after the seek, the audio itself moves to the correct offset, but the reported time is too large, often larger than the length of the track.

I found that at line 1547 of STKAudioPlayer.m, delta is sometimes negative, which leads to the player grossly overreporting the track's progress after a seek.

I'm not sure how it gets the incorrect value, but for our purposes, wrapping those lines in an if (delta > 0) { } clause corrects the issue.

It seems to particularly happen when the queued items have recently been changed, and the playback is buffering.

Anyone know what's happening here, and whether it represents a bug in seeking in StreamingKit, a misunderstanding on our part of how to use it, or both/neither?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this? facing the same issue with incorrect progress reported

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue and fixed it using:

https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit/issues/219

STKAudioPlayer.m change:

look for line:

```
OSSpinLockLock(&currentEntry->spinLock);
currentEntry->seekTime -= delta;
OSSpinLockUnlock(&currentEntry->spinLock);
```

and enclose it in the if statement to check if delta >0

```
if (delta > 0) {
                OSSpinLockLock(&currentEntry->spinLock);
                currentEntry->seekTime -= delta;
                OSSpinLockUnlock(&currentEntry->spinLock);
            }
```